# pecl install trader ends in ERROR: `phpize' failed

Tags: installation, pecl

I'm trying to install the trader extension.
I successfully installed pear/pecl.
When first running the command "pecl install trader" I had some issues on folders that were not writable, so I manually give those read/write permissions.
Now I'm at the point I get "ERROR: `phpize' failed"

Please how to get this solved? 
I run mamp server on a mac 10.6.8

---

```
computer-van-gebruiker:~ Gebruiker$ sudo pecl install trader
Password:
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Downloader.php on line 593

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/local/pear/share/pear/PEAR/Downloader.php on line 593
downloading trader-0.4.0.tgz ...
Starting to download trader-0.4.0.tgz (298,434 bytes)
...........................done: 298,434 bytes

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/PackageFile/v2/Validator.php on line 870

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/local/pear/share/pear/PEAR/PackageFile/v2/Validator.php on line 870
332 source files, building
running: phpize
grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:
Zend Module Api No:
Zend Extension Api No:
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.

ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be more specific about PEAR/PECL and PHP version.

---

Your problem's source is that you're missing the development package for PHP that contains the C header files.